# SSIS Azure BLOB / DW Upload task error

Tags: sql-server, azure, ssis, blob

When trying to load a text file using the Azure SQL DW Upload Task in SSIS, I get the following error:

> Error: 0x0 at Azure SQL DW Upload Task, Azure SQL DW Upload Task:
>   Failed to upload to blob storage. Unable to create Azure Blob
>   container. Endpoint: https://[removed].blob.core.windows.net/,
>   Container Name: [myContainer]. The remote server returned an error: (403)
>   Forbidden. The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden

Tthe SSIS task is failing.I also tried the BLOB upload task and that fails. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

### Cause

When a client accesses a storage account using a TLS version that does not meet the minimum TLS version configured for the account ( you have configured the minimum TLS version as TLS1.2), Azure Storage returns error code 400 error (Bad Request) and a message indicating that the TLS version that was used is not permitted for making requests against this storage account.

### Resolution

The TLS version used by Azure Feature Pack follows system .NET Framework settings. To use TLS 1.2, add a REG_DWORD value named SchUseStrongCrypto with data 1 under the following two registry keys (depend on .net framework version you are using in visual studio- you can find that from help menu in VS):

- HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft.NETFramework\v4.0.30319
- HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft.NETFramework\v4.0.30319

### More information

To test that the minimum required TLS version for a storage account forbids calls made with an older version, you can configure a client to use an older version of TLS. For more information about configuring a client to use a specific version of TLS, see Configure Transport Layer Security (TLS) for a client application in [this link](https://apc01.safelinks.protection.outlook.com/?url=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fazure%2Fstorage%2Fcommon%2Ftransport-layer-security-configure-client-version&data=04%7C01%7CMohamed.Darwish%40intergen.co.nz%7C058d7d1e8ca6402b5dc008d918e513e5%7Cf6ac78139a904377b87eb394e85cc5fc%7C0%7C0%7C637568194477571172%7CUnknown%7CTWFpbGZsb3d8eyJWIjoiMC4wLjAwMDAiLCJQIjoiV2luMzIiLCJBTiI6Ik1haWwiLCJXVCI6Mn0%3D%7C1000&sdata=zcxAnexiXMN%2Bdnn9rrn8W7cgQoIxVpN%2F0q%2BhMVWWbKw%3D&reserved=0).

When you enforce a minimum TLS version for your storage account (your storage account configuration sets the minimum TLS version to TLS 1.2) , you risk rejecting requests from clients that are sending data with an older version of TLS.

### Reference documentation

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/azure-feature-pack-for-integration-services-ssis?view=sql-server-ver15#use-tls-12
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/transport-layer-security-configure-minimum-version?tabs=portal#test-the-minimum-tls-version-from-a-client

Answer (score 2):

For anyone who deosn't want to beat their head against the wall, here was the issue / solution:

I had "PackageProtectionLevel" set to "DoNotSaveSensitive" so I used Package Parameters to configure Password / SecurityToken and then set those as the task values with an expression. SSIS shold have thrown a better error, but at least its solved

Comment: Some more context: I tried to load the file through various other means and it was working. The easiest way to test w/o SSIS in the mix was to use the "Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer" (similar to Cloudberry blob explorer) to try an upload a file. Once that worked, I decided to focus on things specific to SSIS an d I had come across a similar problem with a 3rd party Salesforce task prior.

Answer (score 1):

I had "PackageProtectionLevel" set to "DoNotSaveSensitive" so I used Package Parameters to configure Password / SecurityToken and then set those as the task values with an expression. SSIS shold have thrown a better error, but at least its solved

Kindly elaborate. I tried changing "PackageProtectionLevel", but no luck.